# How to reply a custom header using a webhook triggered by an API

Tags: webhooks

I need to know what am I doing wrong with my integration. I will explain first our main goal.

1. We need to detect new synced projects or created projects on Everhour API using a webhook.
2. Use that webhook to trigger automation on Zapier and do other APIs we need to do.

The process of creating a webhook using their API is like this:

1. Use the create a webhook endpoint ( [link](https://everhour.docs.apiary.io/#reference/0/webhooks/update-project) )
2. Pass the custom webhook(I created on Pipedream with custom header)

The Everhour API requirements say that I need to reply back a custom header of **"X-Hook-Secret "**:

[image]

So far I have created a webhook on Pipedream which you can create a custom header response see reference here:

[image]

This is the request body from the Everhour API to create a webhook, I passed in the Pipedream's custom webhook created.
[image]

Now, the problem is when I create a new project on Everhour the webhook doesn't get triggered. I don't know if it's because of the custom webhook from Pipedream that I miss something or else others.

Any useful tips will be a huge help.